# Use git-svn to work on an SVN repository with a non-standard layout

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am working on an SVN repo, `/path/to/svn/repo`, with this layout:

```
|--aaa/ #empty
|--branches/ #currently on r35, continuing...
|--|--file1
|--|--file2
|--|--file3
|--|--dir1/
|--|--dir2/
|--|--dir3/
|--tags/ #empty
|--trunk/ #empty
```

I use this command:

```
$ git svn clone -s /path/to/svn/repo
#some outputs...
#git checkout master to track r1 (or something like that).
```

Then I get a directory `repo`, which contains only `.git/`.

`git branch -ra` outputs:

```
* master
  remotes/dir1
  remotes/dir2
  remotes/dir3
  remotes/trunk
```

Now I can checkout `dir1`, `dir2`, and `dir3`, but there is no `file1`, `file2`, `file3`, etc.

How can I checkout files *and* directories under the `branches/` directory as a whole branch That is, how can I use git-svn working with others who still use SVN?

Part of `./git/config`:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = /path/to/svn/repo
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
    branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/*
    tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the way I understand it the /branches folder in your svn repository doesn't contain a list of branches, but rather a copy of your code and that is the location where all development takes place?

I would suggest trying out the following if my assumption above is correct.

execute the following command (although adapt it to your conditions): `git svn clone "http://svn-server.local/path_to_repository" "my_git_repository" --authors-file="users.txt" --trunk="branches" --no-metadata`

Now, why not point the "trunk" to the trunk of the SVN repository? According to your question that folder seems to be empty and therefore not be of any importance.